# How do you change the height of an embedded TikTok widget without clipping the embedded video?

Tags: css, tiktok

[TikTok offers an embedded API for developers](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/embed-videos) to view TikToks on other websites. From the documentation, they mention the following:

> Embedded videos come with adaptive length-to-width ratio

My presumption is that when I change the embedded video's container's height, the length/width will adapt to it. This, however, isn't working out too well for me. Setting the size of the element containing the embed to `500px` code does nothing, and the embedded TikTok video overflows with a height of about `700px`. Changing the height of the blockquote with `.tiktok-embed` has a different effect: It does change the size of the embedded video's iframe, but the content inside doesn't attempt to fit this, and it gets cut off instead. *I would like to set a height that is smaller than default, and have the video adapt to the size I have chosen.*

I have a reproducible case [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tiktok-embed-y8uce). How do I make it so that I can change the height of the embed to a smaller height without the embed being clipped?